# Change list of reasons offered when voting to close a question?

Tags: discussion

When you vote to close a question you'll be offered a list of reasons. I wonder if it is possible to edit that list and if so, I'd like to start a discussion about some changes to it.

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

The above reason opens up a list of alternative sites, but only the Craft CMS Meta site is listed. It would be nice if there was also Stack Overflow.

> Bug reports in Craft CMS or in a plugin are off-topic as they are unlikely to help others and can't easily be found by those who can fix them. Instead, submit bug reports directly to the vendor of the product being used. See: How do I submit a bug/issue with Craft?

There are many open questions that do actually fall into this category. But most of them already have useful reponses in the comments and answers. Information about how to temporarily fix the bug, when to expect a bugfix or which version you need to update to when it got fixed already, would all be removed from our SE when we are strict and close those questions.

Because I know this close reason exists, it's kind of tempting for me to click that button. After I did, I feel sorry. See latest example: [Redactor deleting <b> <i> and other inline markup](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/13402/125)

Answer (score 4):

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Making the list more useful would be an obvious win, and while we can edit the message itself I'm not sure that we have any control over the site(s) listed. Perhaps one of the other moderators knows otherwise!

> Bug reports in Craft CMS or in a plugin are off-topic as they are unlikely to help others and can't easily be found by those who can fix them. Instead, submit bug reports directly to the vendor of the product being used. See: How do I submit a bug/issue with Craft?

Narrowly-focused bugs are easy enough to close, but you're right, it seems like more broad bug-related Q&A has potential value. I don't know whether it's the best practice for Stack Exchange, but I think it makes sense to remain diligent about weeding out quiet, edge-case bugs and making room for those that describe and solve problems that'd help a fair number of people.

But I'd be most interested in P&T's perspective on this—I imagine that bugs identified exclusively on SE could diminish the effectiveness of their support workflow.